# V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service Problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase for just Analytics. I implemented yesterday Firebase successfully. In fact I did not get any runtime error but I noticed in Logcat.

After 2-3 seconds, this message is seen in Logcat.

> V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Analytics data is very important for me. As a result, I want to make sure this Analytics data is **completely** correct. I don't want inaccurate data when it comes to analytics.

As you know, in Firebase Analytics **session duration** is important. If firebase is disconnected from the service, then **session duration** probably won't calculated correctly.

Finally, What do you think about this situation?

Should I continue to suspect? If so, how can I solve this problem?

or

Can we say no problem? Session duration and other metrics will be calculated perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a verbose log message.  It doesn't mean that you're losing any data.

If you have concerns about the way any Firebase SDKs are working, please [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for help.

Answer (score 0):

V/FA is Firebase info (verbose)
A session expires when there 30 minutes by default that none of the app's activities is the current activity. If the user exits the app for a shorter period than the session timeout and then restarts it, the session continues. If the user exits the app for longer than the session timeout, then the session ends.

[doc , check setSessionTimeoutDuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics)